# How to produce a trapezoid like format for headings using CSS only?

Tags: css

I want to create headings format like below:

```
       --- Chapter 01 ---
          Introduction: 
  Why we need to learn it and How ?
---------------------------------------


       --- Chapter 02 ---
          Overview: 
  Get ourselves ready for the journey ?
---------------------------------------
```

I am using MarkDown editor, when I input  `### Chapter 01 <br/> Introduction: <br/> Why we need to ....`, they are converted to `<h3><span> Chapter 01 ....</span></h3>`.

I am wondering what is the best (simple, robust) way to achieve this using purely CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the dashes are purely visual indicators they can be added through pseudo before and after elements.

Although CSS does allow some styling of the first-line pseudo element this is limited. We can use it to blank out anything underneath - using a background - but we cannot add pseudo elements to it.

This snippet adds these pseudo elements to the span instead.

```css
h3 span {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

h3 span::first-line {
  background-color: white;
}

h3 span {
  position: relative;
}

h3 span::before {
  content: '- - - Chapter 00 - - -';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
}

h3 span::after {
  content: '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  rz-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <span> Chapter 01<br/>Introduction:<br/>Why we need to learn it and How ?
  </span>
</h3>
<h3>
  <span> Chapter 02<br/>Overview:<br/>Get ourselves ready for the journey ?
  </span>
</h3>
```

Note - if the Chapter numbers go beyond 99 this styling will need adjustment as it is getting the positioning of the dashes on the first line right by using the word Chapter and two digits in the pseudo element.